# Problem with reading Excel file in CPLEX OPL

Tags: cplex, opl, ilog

I have a problem with reading the data from the excel file and getting the error message  "Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: Problem accessing the Excel file". I am using the Cplex Version: 12.6.2.0 and my excel version is 2013. I also tried on another computer but still could not fix the problem. Does anyone know what is the reason?

Comment: Do you run CPLEX on Windows ?

Comment: yes, Alex. I could not solve it yet.

Comment: Does it due to excel deactivation? Since excel always starts with a prompt that you need activation.

Comment: Do you have a Mac or a Windows machine ?

Comment: Check that you haven't got the file open in Excel at the same time - Excel locks the file while it is open

Comment: @AlexFleischer I am solving on windows 10.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick Yeah I checked that also but I  am still getting the error when the excel file is closed.